Magento 2 Custom Module - Adding Category IDs programatically
system.xml file

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="specials_subcategory" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Category Specials</label>
            <tab>ThreeYearOrders</tab>
            <resource>Gelmar_SpecialsSubCategory::config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Settings</label>
                <field id="run_specials_logic" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Update Category Specials</label>
                    <button class="action specials" type="button">
                        <span>Update</span>
                    </button>
                    <action>
                        <url path="gelmar/specials/run" />
                    </action>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>

This is my system.xml file. The settings label and button both display but the button has no text. I simply just want the button to say "Update". Please advise or give suggestions.
Next I need help with my functionality. Below I have my Run.php file which is supposed to add the corresponding category ID to the product if it is in the specials category. So for example if I have a product that is in my Bathroom category and is on special it should add to the Bathroom specials category. I have double checked the IDs and they are all correct however it does not seem to be working.
Run.php file

<?php

namespace Gelmar\SpecialsSubCategory\Controller\Adminhtml\Specials;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Run extends Action
{
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $categoryLinkManagement;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        ProductCollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagement
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->categoryLinkManagement = $categoryLinkManagement;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Category IDs
        $specialsCategoryId = 206;
        $mapping = [
            249 => 259,
            5   => 260,
            21  => 261,
            19  => 262,
            24  => 263,
            28  => 264,
            53  => 265
        ];

        // Get all products in the Specials category (206)
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $specialsCategoryId]);

        // Consider adding pagination or limiting the collection size
        // $productCollection->setPageSize(100)->setCurPage(1);

        // Loop through the products
        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();

            // Use array_intersect() for better performance
            $categoriesToAdd = array_intersect(array_keys($mapping), $categoryIds);
            $newCategoryIds = array_merge($categoryIds, array_map(function($id) use ($mapping) {
                return $mapping[$id];
            }, $categoriesToAdd));

            // Ensure no duplicates
            $newCategoryIds = array_unique($newCategoryIds);

            // Only update if categories have changed
            if ($newCategoryIds !== $categoryIds) {
                try {
                    $this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories($product->getSku(), $newCategoryIds);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // Log the error or handle it as needed
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Error assigning categories to product %1: %2', $product->getSku(), $e->getMessage()));
                }
            }
        }

        // Display success message in the admin
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Specials category update completed successfully.'));

        // Redirect back to the config page
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/specials_subcategory');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}

I am not sure if my Run.php file is incorrect or if my system.xml file is incorrect. Basically what I want to happen is to be able to click a button on the admin side and then it updates the products that are on special to add the necessary category IDs such as Bathroom specials and then has a message to say all products have been updated. Please advise and give suggestions

for button and controller to work, try below reference code and amend changes accordingly
<field id="sent" translate="label" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label></label>
    <button_label>Test Now</button_label>
    <button_url>adminhtml/smtp/test</button_url>
    <frontend_model>Mageplaza\Smtp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
</field>


    <?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Smtp
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

namespace Mageplaza\Smtp\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

/**
 * Class Button
 * @package Magento\Paypal\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config
 */
class Button extends Field
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'system/config/button.phtml';

    /**
     * Unset scope
     *
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope();

        return parent::render($element);
    }

    /**
     * Get the button and scripts contents
     *
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $originalData = $element->getOriginalData();
        $this->addData([
            'button_label' => $originalData['button_label'],
            'button_url'   => $this->getUrl($originalData['button_url'], ['_current' => true]),
            'html_id'      => $element->getHtmlId(),
        ]);

        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}


Thanks for your response but please could you give more detail, as I am slightly confused. Im assuming I will replace my field id="run_specials_logic" field with the first code snippet you provided. Then what do I do with the second code snippet you provided? Do I add this to my controller or create a new file?

Yours will be
<field id="run_specials_logic" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
        <label></label>
        <button_label>Update</button_label>
        <button_url>gelmar/specials/run</button_url>
        <frontend_model>Gelmar\SpecialsSubCategory\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
    </field>

That will be new file Gelmar\SpecialsSubCategory\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Button

Ok thank again for your help. So I will edit my system.xml file to have that code snippet. Then I will create the new file in that directory but what must the file name be and will it be .PHP? So must I create the file and name it Button.php?

Yeah Button.php will be the file name
